# Prove that $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $T\in$ $\mathscr L$($\mathbb C^4$) and the only eigenvalues of T are 3, 5, and 8. I'm trying to show that $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2=0.$

What I have in mind so far is that the zeros of the minimal polynomial of T are the eigenvalues, therefore the minimal polynomial of T is a multiple of (x-3)(x-5)(x-8). Additionally, since the characteristic polynomial of T has degree 4, then the minimal polynomial has at most degree 4. Since the minimal polynomial has at most degree 4, then it follows that $ (T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial, which would imply that $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2=0.$

Is my reasoning correct? Or is there another way of solving the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you're right. $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2$ is multiple of any possible characteristic polynomial of $T$ ,i.e, $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)(T-8I)$,
$(T-3I)(T-5I)^2(T-8I)$ or $(T-3I)(T-5I)(T-8I)^2$. let $f(T)$ be characteristic polynomial. $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2 = f(T)g(T)$ for some g(T). So $(T-3I)^2(T-5I)^2(T-8I)^2 = f(T)g(T) = 0. g(T)=0 $

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial must be $c(t)=(t-3)^m(t-5)^n(t-8)^r$; $m,n,r>0$ with $m+n+r=4$. This gives the bounds for each of $m,n$ and $t$ i.e. $m=1$ or $2$, $n=1$ or $2$, $r=1$ or $2$. For any choice of $m,n$ and $r$, $c(t)$ divides $(t-3)^2(t-5)^2(t-8)^2$.